# Audio Kit iOS Detecting pitch / frequency of short mic input such as taps

Tags: ios, audio, audiokit

I am trying to create an app where the user is able to record a small audio clip - or realtime audio from mic and make a brief noise such as a tap. The app then analyses the frequency or pitch of this in order to remember it later.

I came across an awesome framework called Audio kit and this seems to have a really good sample app that will at least get me started. http://audiokit.io/examples/MicrophoneAnalysis/

However if running this does not give me usable results for short bursts of audio, for instance a tap on the desk vs clap.

I appreciate this example is more for vocal or musical pitch detection -

```
func setupPlot() {
    let plot = AKNodeOutputPlot(mic, frame: audioInputPlot.bounds)
    plot.plotType = .rolling
    plot.shouldFill = true
    plot.shouldMirror = true
    plot.color = UIColor.blue
    audioInputPlot.addSubview(plot)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    AKSettings.audioInputEnabled = true
    mic = AKMicrophone()
    tracker = AKFrequencyTracker(mic)
    silence = AKBooster(tracker, gain: 0)
}
@objc func updateUI() {
        if tracker.amplitude > 0.1 {
        frequencyLabel.text = String(format: "%0.1f", tracker.frequency)

        var frequency = Float(tracker.frequency)
        while frequency > Float(noteFrequencies[noteFrequencies.count - 1]) {
            frequency /= 2.0
        }
        while frequency < Float(noteFrequencies[0]) {
            frequency *= 2.0
        }

        var minDistance: Float = 10_000.0
        var index = 0

        for i in 0..<noteFrequencies.count {
            let distance = fabsf(Float(noteFrequencies[i]) - frequency)
            if distance < minDistance {
                index = i
                minDistance = distance
            }
        }
        let octave = Int(log2f(Float(tracker.frequency) / frequency))
        noteNameWithSharpsLabel.text = "\(noteNamesWithSharps[index])\(octave)"
        noteNameWithFlatsLabel.text = "\(noteNamesWithFlats[index])\(octave)"
    }
    amplitudeLabel.text = String(format: "%0.2f", tracker.amplitude)
}
```

I checked on the audio kit site and it advised to post questions here with the appropriate tag

So my question is  - is it possible to do this with the framework - ideally detect the frequency of a short piece of audio reliably enough to distinguish between two loud taps (for instance someone slapping their chest & then their thigh)

Or are there alternative frameworks I should look at (I am an iOS dev)

Comment: I wonder if you could use the amplitude tracker to try to tell the difference between those two sounds, seems like the clap would be a lot louder.

Comment: Hey thanks, however I really want to be able to determine based on the audio pitch rather than volume if its possible - obviously the pitches need to differ enough to be distinguisable

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to do is to determine whether there exists a statistically significant difference between the sounds of the two types of taps.

You might record a bunch of samples of each, and then examine them with an audio analysis tool, such as a spectrogram using Audacity or MatLab.  Then you might be able to look for some particular framework than can reliably detect any difference you've found, if possible.  Or if you can gather thousands of labeled sound samples, you might be able to feed them to some deep learning tool, and use the results with iOS MLKit for inference.

Comment: I'd add to this that you don't want to machine learn an entire sound sample, because you don't care about things like the tail of the sound.  You want to put all your attention on the initial impulse of the sound.  Ideally if you could get a sense of the "attack" of the sound that would probably yield sufficiently accurate results.

Comment: Hey thanks for the comments and answers - this all sounds really logical, however the idea is that this can be done on the fly - ML and Audio analysis tools outside of what can be done in app will only help for initial identification of potential characteristics. Ideally with the app I want to be able to identify the difference between 2 percussive sounds and perform actions off the back